# Import commonjs library in svelte/rollup app

Tags: svelte, es6-modules, commonjs, rollup

I am developing a svelte-based electron app to learn the framework (I have no previous experience with svelte or rollup).

When importing the library modbus-serial into the App.svelte component of a new app (`import ModbusRTU from "modbus-serial"` or `const ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial")`), I keep getting the following error on the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Note: I am aware that the library is implemented for nodejs. I am in fact trying to port to svelte, for learning purposes, an IoT app previously built with electron + react and electron + vue. With react and vue I had no problems importing the library.

Below my rollup.config.js:

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production }),
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production
        }),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

Comment: Sharing your `rollup.config.js` would be helpful, as this should be a problem with either `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` or `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`. If you don't have either plugins added in your config, adding them before `rollup-plugin-svelte` should help.

Comment: Hi jason, thanks for the comment. I added my `rollup.config.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be caused by the mixing of commonjs `require` & esm `import` statements in the same project. Adding `transformMixedEsModules` to the config of `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` should help somewhat resolve the issue:

```js
// rollup.config.js
// ...
commonjs({
  transformMixedEsModules: true,
}),
// ...
```

Do note however, that I've personally ran into tonnes of issues bringing modules targeting node specifically to the web. This is because `require` is by design dynamic, thus if used in ways that can't be statically analyzed, you may need to explore more hacky workarounds, listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs#options). Other than that, shims, shams, & polyfills of node modules aren't always 100% implemented either.

However, you're in luck! Since you're targetting `electron`, you may look into importing (`require`-ing) these modules via the main process & using IPC to communicate with it instead, see [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main) for more info.